# What processes are using how much of my GPU?

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu

I sometimes have an issue where *something* decides to take up 100% of my GPUs clock cycles. Activity Monitor only shows this as a solid block of usage in the activity monitor, but it doesn't give me *any* information as to who's using it.

With Nvidia/CUDA, I could use `nvidia-smi` to tell me this, but I cannot find any equivalent on OS-X.

How do I tell what's using the GPU?

I have the rMBP with the AMD Radeon Pro 560 and an external AMD Radeon RX 570. I didn't have the activity monitor open the last time this happened, but the last time I had the symptoms it was the 560.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of where you're seeing that the GPU, rather than the CPU is at 100% utilisation? Model no. (Apple Menu -> About This Mac -> System Report -> Hardware) and version number of OSX (Apple Menu -> About This Mac) might be helpful to know.

Comment: It happens randomly so I can't produce a screen-shot on-demand. However, it's from the builtin Activity Monitor in its "GPU History" window where, for a period of time, the indicator is completely blue (i.e. 100% GPU load). Notwithstanding the irrelevancy of additional hardware/software information to the question at hand, here's the computer info: MacBookPro14,3 running OS X 10.14 (18A336e).

Comment: You're running a beta OS. You should report this to Apple.

Comment: @Tetsujin While I agree, that is not relevant to this question.